# How can I set a header showing the current section?

Tags: header-footer, appendices

A few of the appendices in my document contain code covering a lot of pages, but those pages have nothing else than code (and page numbers). How can I put a header showing what's the current appendix, starting from the *second* page of each appendix? The image below shows the undesired results.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
\pagestyle{headings}
```

to print the current section name in the header.

If you need more precision than that, you can use, eg `fancyhdr` and craft your own heading layout. See http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf for details.

Comment: Do you know how to enable it, only in the pages where the section title is not already present?

Comment: @Tomas: it should work if you put `\pagestyle{headings}` right after `\appendix`

Comment: It does work, but I didn't wanted to get this: http://oi53.tinypic.com/x8w1g.jpg I don't want the headers in the pages that have the section start.

Comment: In addition to what you already have, add `\thispagestyle{empty}` right after `\section{..}`